# How to prevent malicious input in Spring JPA+Spring REST+jHipster

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, jhipster, spring-rest

I'm new to Spring JPA/jHipster.
My question is inspired by the jHipster talk by Julien Dubois: https://youtu.be/R3jm2qmqctI?t=43m7s

Assume you have a bank account with operations on it (+100$ for restaurant, -50$ ATM, ...)
Each bank account has an owner of course.

The payload of a POST REST call that creates the operation could look like this:
{"amount":100,"description":"restaurant","bankaccount":{"id":1136}}

The id of the bankaccount is unique and (for the sake of this example) would have been sent to me earlier via another REST call.

Unfortunately, nothing prevents a malicious user to change this value. One could simply guess the id of a bankaccount owned by someone else, and then the operation would be added to that one.

I have not (yet) seen examples that deal with this problem.
Should I explicitly check if the bankaccount is owned by the user?
I imagine that this type of verification may cascade through all your entities, causing a lot of extra calls.
Maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Found an interesting article that backs up my worries ;) it even has a name, it's called a direct object reference attack or DOR attack: http://www.jtmelton.com/tag/direct-object-reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's your reponsibility to check in your REST controller or underlying services that an operation is authorized. Spring security offers d[ifferent mechanisms to do it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) in particular by using @PreAuthorize and @PostFilter.

It's also a good thing to use DTOs, this way you can better control what fields of your entities are exposed for reading and writing through the API.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It helps a lot. I'd appreciate it if you can point me to some real examples (on GitHub, ...) I still think I'm missing something or, if not, I believe that there are a lot of vulnerable apps in the wild that have ignored to do those checks.

Comment: Elaborating on this a little bit more...  

Assuming we have 3 entities A, B and C. A has an owner field (referring to the User entity) as well as a set of B's. B has a pointer to A as well as a set of C's. C has a pointer to B. So it's a hierarchy.  

As stated earlier, all the requests can be tampered with.  

So would it be correct/necessary (!) to do this in the create method (the REST endpoint) of C (in pseudocode)?  
  
`entityC.getEntityB().getEntityA().getOwner().equals(currentUser)`  
  
If not, I might have guessed the id of a B that is owned by another user, right?

Comment: RIght, another possibility is to expose ids that are meaningful only for current user. So if user owns 3 accounts, account id 1 would refer to only one of his accounts and this is something that is easy to do using DTOs.